# Joomla 2.5 cant create or edit articles

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

When I try to press "Add new article" or the article for editing an error always pop-up

Error 500
JHtml: Jquery not supported. File not found

But I can view the articles and modify the other things (like: menu, module, etc.)

I'm new to joomla and I only know the basics. Please Help!!!